# Online trend of KPI in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

let's say I have a KPI which is a simple calculation like

`SUMX(FILTER(Table;Table[Date] < Today());Table[Column])`

I would like to plot a time series of the KPI's past values (for example for the first day of every month since 01-01-2014), so for instance it is enough to create a new table - Trend_Table -  with two columns - DATE, KPI and calculate each row's KPI value as

`SUMX(FILTER(Table;Table[Date] < Trend_Table[Date]);Table[Column])`

(it may not exactly work that way in DAX but you get the idea)

The problem is I really want to have online values, which means that once the September begins a new row with DATE = '01-09-2018' should be added automatically to the table 'Tren_Table'.
Is it possible in Power BI? Any referalls greatly welcomed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "online values".

Comment: "which means that once the September begins a new row with DATE = '01-09-2018' should be added automatically to the table 'Tren_Table'. " The trend should update itself once a new batch of data is uploaded to database every first day of month